# Comparing two models using Repeated K-fold Cross Validation

Tags: t-test, cross-validation

I am creating two separate classification models. In order to estimate the performance, I have been using 10-fold cross validation repeated 5 times for each model, resulting in 50 different performance metrics for each model. If I wanted to say for sure that one model's performance was better than another, and that this result is statistically significant, can I calculate the mean of the 50 different runs for each model and then perform a t-test? Are there assumptions being violated if I do this?

Comment: Better do bootstrap estimation of the mean performance and its standard errors.

Answer (score 3):

Update:

I've been doing some reading the past few days and found a few answers. According to Dietterich's paper "[Approximate Statistical Tests for Comparing Supervised Classification Learning Algorithms](https://direct.mit.edu/neco/article/10/7/1895/6224/Approximate-Statistical-Tests-for-Comparing)", standard t-tests have a high type I error (a significant difference is found between the models even when there isn't actually one) when used on cross validated results. According to Nadeau and Bengio's paper "[Inference for the Generalization Error](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1024068626366#article-info)", this is due to the underestimation of the variance the samples caused by them not being truly independent - the test data is re-used in other folds.

To get around this, I found another paper "[Evaluating the replicability of significance tests for comparing learning algorithms](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24775-3_3)" that recommends the use of a "corrected" version of the t-test for repeated k-fold cross validation (which was used in my original models). The corrected version is:

$$t= \frac{\frac{1}{kr}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{r} x_{ij}}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{kr} + \frac{n_2}{n_1})\hat{\sigma}^2}}$$

Where $k$ is a given fold, $r$ is the number of repeats, $x_{ij}$ is the difference between models in a given run $j$ and fold $i$. The numerator is an estimate for the mean, while the variance can be estimated as $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{kr-1}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{r}(x_{ij}-m).^2$

(EDIT by @Firebug: $n_1$ is the number of instances used for training, $n_2$ is the number of instances used for testing)

This version seems to be more consistent and replicable in experiments according to the author, so it seems like a safer solution than a naive t-test.

Comment: What are n1 and n2?

Comment: @HaneenSu $n_1$ is the number of instances used for training, $n_2$ is the number of instances used for testing

Comment: I've added this info to the answer, if someone disagrees feel free to revert it